# Python name jpg with timestamp

Tags: python

(Solved)I am not understanding how to save my final jpg with a timestamp of the actual time and date.
I can successfully save my camera jpg with my code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Image
import ImageChops
import sys
import glob
import os
import datetime
# get the date to add to caption and file name
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

try:
dir_images = sys.argv[1]
dir_results = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
print "No directories specified."

images = []
os.chdir('/media/SamsungDisk3/uhvo_replacement_test/images' )

for files in glob.glob("*.jpg"): 
images.append(files)
if len(images) is 2: 
    print images[0]
    background = Image.open(images[0])
    overlay = Image.open(images[1])

    print images[1]
    background = background.convert("RGBA")
    overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")


    filename = "/home/tim/Desktop/final_stacked_images/final_result_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H:%M:%S") + ".jpg"
ImageChops.lighter(background, overlay).save(filename)
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit....
Thank you.

Comment: Is your question "how to format a time stamp as a string?" If so take a look at this https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: Jason,,The formats i could easily find online.It was the integrating it into the code and making it work that confused me....

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageChops.lighter(background, overlay).save('/home/tim/Desktop/final_stacked_images/final/result_{}.jpg'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s'))
```

... should sort you. If not, leave a comment with the error and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Try now, I just missed a character

Comment: Still throwing an error....  `File "/media/SamsungDisk3/uhvo_replacement_test/images/script_2.py", line 31
    
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`  >....I have been looking on the web and it seems to not like the end of the last line....Like maybe i am not closing it right....

Comment: Maybe change 'if len(images) is 2:' to 'if len(images) == 2:' and see how far you get?

Comment: If that doesn't work, feel free to drop me a line on IM at hd1@jsc.d8u.us

Comment: Would you care to accept the answer now that you sorted it?